# Tracking counts for Like,Share,Comment of a content shared on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there any API available which provide the result with counts for a specific content like 
How many Like ? How many share ? How many Comment ?

Thanks.

Comment: For company updates, it's well documented here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#get_update_comments - but for user profile shares, I have no idea.